# How do I achieve a titlebar with buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've been Googling around on tutorials and other docs on how I can do this kind of layout in Android:

[image]

I've been dragging and dropping every widget there is in Eclipse onto the XML to find the one where the Title Bar is similar with the + button, the refresh button as well.

Also what is this kind of tabs called? I looked around and it is suggested it is PageViewer?

Please bear in mind I'm learning Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is probably a ViewPager implementation with Tabs+Swipes which you can get from creating a new project using the latest Android SDK and choose Tab+Swipe navigation. The layout for the list here is simply a ListFragment with a custom adapter.

This is part of the ActionBar pattern on Android, and by using the support library or ActionBar Shelock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) you can target the older phones as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's called an `Actionbar`.  If you are using Android 3.0+, then you can use it natively.  If not, take a look at ActionbarSherlock.

Links:

http://actionbarsherlock.com

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

That is an [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), which is only available in Android 3.0+. The tabs are standard tabs that have a special API when dealing with Action Bars. If you want to use the Action Bar in a release prior to 3.0, I recommend [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).